# Guessing number game python

Tags: python, loops, input, while-loop

So i'm working on a guessing number game and one of the requirements is for the "range" of numbers to be updated so that the user with have an easier time with their guess'. I created a new input for when the number is either too high or too low. However, i'm not very good with loops and I can't figure out why my loop is repeating only once without my pasting the code over and over again. Can anyone help so the elif statements will repeat until the number is correct?

This is my code thus far...

```
import random
random_number = random.randint(1,100)
tries = 0
while tries < 800:
  guess = input("Guess a random number between 1 and 100.")       
  tries += 1
  try:
    guess_num = int(guess)
  except:
    print("That's not a whole number!")
    break

  if not guess_num > 0 or not guess_num < 101:
    print("That number is not between 1 and 100.")
    break

  elif guess_num == random_number:
    print("Congratulations! You are correct!")
    print("It took you {} tries.".format(tries))
    break

  elif guess_num > random_number:
      print("Sorry that number is too high.")
      guess_high = input("Guess a number between 0 and {} .".format(guess_num))

  elif guess_num < random_number:
      print("Sorry that number is too low.")
      guess_low = input("Guess a number between {} and 100 .".format(guess_num))

  else:
      print("Sorry, but my number was {}".format(random_number))
      print("You are out of tries. Better luck next time.")
```

Comment: You are not updating the actual ranges, but only printing out

Comment: so how could I update the ranges so it fits to narrow down the users inputs?

Comment: You shouldn't break unless the answer was correct.  Remove all other occurrences of `break`

Comment: I uploaded code that updates the range every time, minor modifications to your code as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
random_number = random.randint(1,100)
tries = 0
guess = input("Guess a random number between 1 and 100.")       
while tries < 800:
  tries += 1
  try:
    guess_num = int(guess)
  except:
    print("That's not a whole number!")
    break

  if not guess_num > 0 or not guess_num < 101:
    print("That number is not between 1 and 100.")
    break

  elif guess_num == random_number:
    print("Congratulations! You are correct!")
    print("It took you {} tries.".format(tries))
    break

  elif guess_num > random_number:
      print("Sorry that number is too high.")
      guess = input("Guess a number between 0 and {} .".format(guess_num))

  elif guess_num < random_number:
      print("Sorry that number is too low.")
      guess = input("Guess a number between {} and 100 .".format(guess_num))

else:
  print("Sorry, but my number was {}".format(random_number))
  print("You are out of tries. Better luck next time.")
```

Comment: Your code won't work as it doesn't address arbitrary ranges, such as from 25-30.

Comment: (See my other post) Since a user can play using a "binary search", I would recommend limiting the number of tries to less than 800 (about 8 would suffice).  It would make testing the last `else:` faster.

Answer (score 0):

For which case does your loop only repeats once?

The loop would break (since you have a break statement in line 15 under the "if not guess_num > 0 or not guess_num < 101:") if the input guess is less than 0 or greater than 100.

If the user input an incorrect guess between 1 and 100, then the code does loop and hence the user is asked to input another number.

Although it does loop, the loop is not updating the range.
What you can do is set range_min and range_max as variables and change these variables according to if the guess is too low or too high.
See the following code:

```
import random
random_number = random.randint(1,100)
tries = 0
range_min = 0
range_max = 100
while tries < 800:
  guess = input("Guess a random number between " + str(range_min +1) + " and " +  str(range_max))       
  tries += 1
  try:
    guess_num = int(guess)
  except:
    print("That's not a whole number!")
    break

  if not guess_num > range_min or not guess_num < (range_max+1):
    print("That number is not between str(range_min +1) + " and " +      str(range_max)")
    break

  elif guess_num == random_number:
    print("Congratulations! You are correct!")
    print("It took you {} tries.".format(tries))
    break

  elif guess_num > random_number:
      print("Sorry that number is too high.")
      guess_high = input("Guess a number between 0 and {} .".format(guess_num))
range_max = guess_num

  elif guess_num < random_number:
      print("Sorry that number is too low.")
      guess_low = input("Guess a number between {} and 100 .".format(guess_num))
range_min = guess_num

  else:
      print("Sorry, but my number was {}".format(random_number))
          print("You are out of tries. Better luck next time.")
```

Comment: My elif narrows down the guess so that the user has an easier time either guessing above their number if its too low or below their number if its too high, but after the new input it goes back to guessing between 1 and 100 and not the updated range

Comment: I edited my answer. The loop does loop when the user input an incorrect guess and ask for a new guess however, it is not updating the range.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not use `break`, as they terminate the while loop.  See python language reference.
2. You should ask only once for `guess_num`.  Remove the two `input` when the guess is too high or too low (BTW variable name `guess` was incorrect).
3. The last condition (out of tries) should be outside the `while` loop, since it will be executed when the number of tries is over 800.
4. Hint.  A user can play this game with the equivlent of a binary search (start with 50, then guess 25 or 75 depending if higher/lower, etc).  You should allow about 8 tries (not 800).

Comment: Yeah thank you haha I had 800 on there for the purpose of trail and error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to update the ranges:

```
import random
random_number = random.randint(1,100)
tries = 0
low = 0
high = 100
while tries < 800:
  if(tries == 0):
    guess = input("Guess a random number between {} and {}.".format(low, high))       
  tries += 1
  try:
    guess_num = int(guess)
  except:
    print("That's not a whole number!")
    break    

  if guess_num < low or guess_num > high:
    print("That number is not between {} and {}.".format(low, high))
    break    

  elif guess_num == random_number:
    print("Congratulations! You are correct!")
    print("It took you {} tries.".format(tries))
    break    

  elif guess_num > random_number:
      print("Sorry that number is too high.")
      high = guess_num
      guess = input("Guess a number between {} and {} .".format(low, high))    

  elif guess_num < random_number:
      print("Sorry that number is too low.")
      low = guess_num
      guess = input("Guess a number between {} and {} .".format(low, high))    

  else:
      print("Sorry, but my number was {}".format(random_number))
      print("You are out of tries. Better luck next time.")
```

Comment: No problem ;) By the way, the final else check doesn't need to be there and can occur outside the while loop (it will never reach that code)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it. Not sure if it works but the approach would be:

```
import random

random_number = random.randint(1,100)
max_tries = 100 
tries = 0
left = 0
right = 100
found = False


def get_number():
    try:
        guess = int(input("Guss a random number between {} and {}".format(left, right)))            
        if guess > right or guess < left:
            print("That number is not between {} and {}".format(left, right))
        return guess
    except:
        print("That's not a whole number!")
        get_number()

def update_range(guess):
    if guess >= left:
        left = guess
    else:
        right = guess        

while tries <= max_tries and not found:
    guess = get_number()
    tries=+1
    if guess == random_number:
        print("Congratulations! You are correct!")
        print("It took you {} tries.".format(tries))
        found = True
    else:
        update_range(guess)

  if not found:
      print("Sorry, but my number was {}".format(random_number))
      print("You are out of tries. Better luck next time.")
```

As you can see I am using **helper functions** in order to reduce the number of if/else structures.

Also **updating the range** is necessary. And thanks to **parametrized strings** I can tell the user what's the range.

I also **set a flag** to know whether the user found the number or not at the end of the game